# How to override .select2-results .select2-highlighted color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used select2 plugin. I have two select input box. I need to both are different highlighted color. Can anyone tell me the solution how to override the highlighted color?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two different select objects, is quite simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".select-1").select2();
 $(".select-2").select2();
});
```

then in your css do:

```
.select-1 select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted {
    background: #5897fb;
 }

.select-2 select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted {
    background: #6d6d6d;
}
```

Edit:

It turns out select2 appends the created suggestion box to the document body, and not the select element it self. One option can be to place the selects inside a parent container and use pass in the dropdownParent option to the constructor:

```
 $("#menuOption1").select2({dropdownParent: "#menuOption1-container"});
```

So you end up with something like this:

Markup:

```
<span id="menuOption1-container">
    <select id="menuOption1"> 
        <option value="1"> One </option>
        <option value="2"> Two </option>
        <option value="3"> Three </option>
        <option value="4"> Four </option>
        <option value="5"> Five </option>
    </select>
</span>

<span id="menuOption2-container">
    <select id="menuOption2"> 
        <option value="a"> Vowel a </option>
        <option value="e"> Vowel e </option>
        <option value="i"> Vowel i </option>
        <option value="o"> Vowel o </option>
        <option value="o"> Vowel u </option>
    </select>
</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menuOption1").select2({dropdownParent: "#menuOption1-container"});
    $("#menuOption2").select2({dropdownParent: "#menuOption2-container"});
});
```

and finally the Css:

```
#menuOption1-container  .select2-results__option--highlighted {
    background-color: #50831F !important;
}

#menuOption2-container  .select2-results__option--highlighted {
   background-color: #28915F !important;
}
```

Here's a live example:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qapuh7t/)

Comment: I have used two different id #menuOption1 and #menuOption2. and css     .select2-results .select2-highlighted{
 background-color: #28915F; 
} it should be applied both id's. i need different both of them.

Comment: Then it should be:
    #menuOption1 select2-results__option select2-results__option--     highlighted {
        background: #5897fb;
     }

     #menuOption2 select2-results__option select2-results__option--    highlighted {
        background: #6d6d6d;
    }

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this question and is having trouble getting `select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted { background-color }` to change from the default blue (#5897fb), make sure that you are not including your css code inside of the element that wraps your select2. The reason is as stated in the first answer:

> It turns out select2 appends the created suggestion box to the document body, not the select element itself.