# option group like horizontal menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, jquery-selectors

i have group option like this:

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
    <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="German Cars">
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

but i want to be it like menu

like this:

[image]

Comment: `<select>` doesn't have ability collapse items, you'll have to make your own select element.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156973/collapse-expand-optgroup-using-select2/52157352

Comment: how can i make that?